# Função do angular não carrega a tempo?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, angularjs-scope, angularjs-services

Quando tento usar no template de um site o seguinte código:

```
<img src="{{getImage(estabelecimento)}}">
```

A imagem carrega corretamente, porém antes de carregar aparece este erro no console:

> GET http://localhost:8080/%7B%7BgetImage(estabelecimento)%7D%7D 404
>   (Not Found)

Tudo me leva a crer que as tags HTML estão sendo carregadas e executadas antes das diretivas do angular, fazendo com que o texto da tag que chama a função apareça no código HTML por alguns milissegundos.

Tem alguma forma de consertar isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente com `ng-src` :

`<img ng-src="{{getImage(estabelecimento)}}">`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Era exatamente isso, obrigado!